# Modules that can be migrated in Magento To MongoDB

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, database, mongo

A NoSQL database to meet the challenges of storing larger catalogues of data, this scalable solution will bring unmatched performance. But as we know , Magento has a large number of tables and those tables have relationships to each other. So we will not be able to completely migrate in one go.

But we can be migrate few modules which make sense to do so? What are the modules that can be migrated or is there any other way that a NoSql database like MongoDB can be used.

I have also read how to connect to MongoDB, but need to know which modules which will increase performance.

Comment: good question @sunel.+1 for for you

Comment: mongogento http://www.ecommerce-performances.com/en/mongogento.php

Comment: but that only has product module to mongodb and also it still uses sql behind the scene . what are the other modules that can be migrated and also fully to mongodb

Comment: @Marius that is not relevant question and mine is entirely different pls verify and remove duplication

Comment: I think the biggest performance issue is the catalog - if you move these information to MongoDB or ElasticSearch, you will increase the performance. We use ElasticSearch for Searching and LayeredNavigation in some projects - all other product data will stay in mySQL to avoid conflicts and have less work.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. Im not sure ALL of Magento would suite a NoSQL style database storage. I can see how using MongoDB, ElasticSearch etc for Products makes sense as its document storage. So different products could contain different types of data to make up a valid product. However for more structure data such as configuration navigation categories I think a relational MySQL database is the better fit.

the problem this creates is that it is very expensive to then open 2 database connections as well as not being able to JOIN on the data sets to link data. Relationships in Mongo ( it doesnt really have them ) is not fun. Neo4J is a graph DB that supports relationships but again core_resource and the category structure I would see little value being in a Document store.

If I had to move modules out from MySQL initial ideas would be:

- Search
- Products
- Invoices / Orders
- Customers

To me these are the modules that store data that would benefit from these NoSQL schemaless styles. Products that are represented by physical document's in the world A4 product sheets that can vary by category manufacturer would be ideal.